# Split row inside of pop up panel while keeping formatting

Tags: scripting

So I have a panel I want to create a split option for. I experimented with box, row and column but was unable to get anywhere. I basiclly just want (S) and (C) on the same menu without extending the panel to be longer.

```
else:
                #C/S Sharpen Split Option
                layout = self.layout
                row = layout.row(align=False)
                split = row.split(percentage=0.5)
                col = split.row()

                Ssharpen = icons.get("Ssharpen")
                CSharpen = icons.get("CSharpen")

                col.operator("ssharpen.objects", text = "(S)", icon_value=Ssharpen.icon_id)
                col.operator("csharpen.objects", text = "(C)", icon_value=CSharpen.icon_id)
```

[image: this is what the menu looks like normally]

this is what the menu looks like normally

[image: this is what it looks like with my attempting to split it]

While the extended menu looks cool I would like it more if I was able to lock it to that layout and had guidance text in the blank area. 
But I would rather it just have both the S and C in a panel thats the same size as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use colum_flow(x) and col.label("for the text")
(colum must be equal to get a nice look)

```
else:
            #C/S Sharpen Split Option
            layout = self.layout
            row = layout.row(align=False)
            split = row.split(percentage=0.5)
            col = split.colum_flow(2)

            Ssharpen = icons.get("Ssharpen")
            CSharpen = icons.get("CSharpen")

            col.operator("ssharpen.objects", text = "(S)", icon_value=Ssharpen.icon_id)
            col.operator("csharpen.objects", text = "(C)", icon_value=CSharpen.icon_id)
```

it is not exactly what you want, but near...

```
import bpy

class SimpleCustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Simple Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_simple_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout.column_flow(2)

        layout.operator("object.duplicate_move", text="Duplicate")
        layout.label("1. use for text")
        layout.label("2. use for text")
        layout.label("3. use for text")


        layout.operator("object.duplicate_move_linked", text="Duplicate Linked")
        layout.operator("object.duplicate_move_linked", text="Duplicate Linked")
        layout.operator("object.duplicate_move_linked", text="Duplicate Linked")
        layout.operator("object.duplicate_move_linked", text="Duplicate Linked")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleCustomMenu)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleCustomMenu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # The menu can also be called from scripts
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=SimpleCustomMenu.bl_idname)
```

[image]

Comment: awesome. I am still fairly confused with it but I will continue messing with it. I feel I am missing something with formatting inside of panel boxes. But this answers my question!

Comment: Zeffii also posted a good example here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44356/fighting-split-col-and-aligning-row-content